# iOS database programming

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I am looking for something that would act as a database for an iOS application. I have read about SQLite, but this seems to be only useful if you want to store the database locally. I want to have multiple people be able to write to the database from multiple phones.

Does anyone have any information? Can you just use a MySQL database?

Not looking for any code, just to be pointed in the right direction, brand new to the topic!

Comment: Who will host the db? One of the phones? Or do you have your own server somewhere?

Comment: @onetrickpony I would have the sever hosted elsewhere

Comment: You'll probably want to simplify the problem set and define a REST interface to the dataset then.  The actual database used is pretty much irrelevant, and completely dependent on what the server solution supports.  The iOS access to it would be through a set of well-defined HTTP requests/responses.

Comment: @david so making a request to a REST server, then getting JSON responses from a database?

Comment: JSON or XML, yes.  At this point JSON is probably the easier mechanism to use.

Comment: If you want to add local caching, you can take a look at RestKit, which also can help with serializing JSON data into native objective-c objects (other than NSDictionary and NSArray)

Comment: Awesome, this is all for my final year project, and we just had a whole assignment about REST interfaces, so this is probably going to mean a lot of reusable code. Thanks for the help. If you want to put it as an answer, ill mark you correct?

Comment: Probably you want to pick a server platform (Windows or Linux, probably, based on what you're comfortable with and have equipment for) and then pick the DB server based on that platform choice.  The server doesn't care that much what brand of client it's talking to, and the client doesn't care too much (so long as you don't get heavy into .NET or some such proprietary protocol).

Comment: Definitely use JSON and REST, unless there's a good reason not.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [**`Couchbase Lite`**](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios) which is an embedded lightweight, document-oriented (`NoSQL`), syncable database engine.